Where can I find Lucan's Crossed Wands battle area?
At the beginning of the game, Sebastian introduced me to Lucan at the Crossed Wands battle area and after I won the match, Lucan told me that I should return later for some more battles.
I'd like to return now, but I don't remember where the location was.
I've been running around all over Hogwarts, but I'm not finding it.
How can I get myself back to the Crossed Wands battle area within Hogwarts?

Crossed Wands take place in the duelling arena near the Floo Flame labelled Clock Tower Courtyard within The South Wing.
Source, here.

That's it. Thank you. Found it.
